# Java Graphics synchronisation issues drawing dynamic data

Tags: graphics, dynamic-data, synchronization

I have a program where I want to draw data that is constantly being updated (it is microhpone-line-data incidentally). The data is an 8000-length array of doubles, I don't really care about 'losing' data which is overriden between takes of the paint method.

In my naive implementation it became obvous that there's synchronisation issues, where the audio-data is updated while the painting routine is under-way.

I'm also aware I'm slightly out-of-date on Java and the Concurrency package it has, but my first response was to just put synchronised blocks around the shared data code. Unsurprisingly this blocks the graphics thread sometimes, so I'm thinking there's probaly a much better way of doing this.

Essentially I just dont have much experience with synchronisation and am screwing things up a bit somewhere. I wonder if someone with a better understanding of these matters might be able to suggest a more elegant solution that doesn't block the graphics thread?

My naive code:

```
Object lock = new Object();
double[] audio = new double[8000]

// array size is always exactly 8000
public update( double[] audio ) {
    synchronized( lock ) {
       this.audio=audio; // and some brief processing
    }
    repaint();
}

public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    synchronized( lock ) {
        // draw the contents of this.audio
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-answer, unless some more intelligent person can offer something better, I just save a reference to the audio array at the beginning of the routine and draw from that, then any updates to the audio buffer do their calculations in a separate array and then assign this.audio to the new array in a single step.

It appears to work, although the paint routine does get an occasional flicker it is nothing like it was, where it was flashing very noticeably about 10% of the time due to synchronised blocking. The audio-data does not update half-way through the drawing routine either. so... problem solved. probably.

```
double[] audio = new double[8000]

// array size is always exactly 8000
public update( double[] audio ) {
   // do any brief processing
   this.audio=audio; // the reference is re-assigned in one step

repaint();
}

public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    audioNow = this.audio; // save the reference
    // draw the contents of audioNow (not this.audio)
}
```